# Asp .net Session is timeout and all data wasn't saved , any idea?

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

I created an web application where a lot of words was needed in the application which take a lot of time and thinking when u need to write it.

Let's suppose the session timeout after 30 minutes,i started writing a lot of words and while thinking and writing the session timeout and redirect to the login page and all written data is lost.

Any idea for this problem except extending session timeout period ???

Comment: you can change the timeout of the session in the web.config. Another option might be to save data to the users cookie because then you won't lose the data when the session times out

Answer (score 0):

Currently your session is created and managed as `In-Process` mode and in this mode you cannot recover session state once it reaches timeout stage. You may set `SQL Server Mode` and [configure your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) for `SQL Server Mode` so your data will be persisted into Sql Server database.

[Profile Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) is an alternate to save the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some ajax function that regularly "calls home" (executes some dummy code on the server). This will keep the session alive as long as that user has this page open.

You might need to explicitly use the Session in that callback, such as

```
Session["LastAccess"] = DateTime.Now;
```

just to keep it alive.

If you execute this call every 15 minutes, the session will not time out and the load on the server is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use asynchronous programming model which allowing some portion of code to be executed on a separate threads.

There are three style of Programming with APM

1. Wait Until Done Model
2. Polling Model
3. Callback Model

Based on your requirement and result you can choose the model which is more appropriate.

For instance, let us say you can to read the file and wait until done and sample code is

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
string filename =
string.Concat(Environment.SystemDirectory, "\\mfc71.pdb");
FileStream strm = new FileStream(filename,
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 1024,
FileOptions.Asynchronous);
// Make the asynchronous call
strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
IAsyncResult result = strm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, null, null);
// Do some work here while you wait
// Calling EndRead will block until the Async work is complete
int numBytes = strm.EndRead(result);
// Don't forget to close the stream
strm.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Read {0} Bytes", numBytes);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer));
```

But creating your threads are not necessary or suggesting, .NET supports a built in thread pool that can be used in many situation where you thinking to create your own threads. Sample code

```
static void WorkWithParameter(object o)
{
string info = (string) o;
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", info,
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
// Slow down thread and let other threads work
Thread.Sleep(10);
}
}
```

Instead of creating a new thread and controlling it, we use the ThreadPool to this work  by using its QueueWorkItem method

```
WaitCallback workItem = new WaitCallback(WorkWithParameter));
if (!ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(workItem, "ThreadPooled"))
{
Console.WriteLine("Could not queue item");
}
```